# Django model isn't persisting data to DB on real-time

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using Django Python framework, and MySQL DBMS.

In the screenshot below, I'm creating the **new_survey_draft** object using the **SurveyDraft.objects.create()** as shown, assuming that it should create a new row in the **surveydraft** DB table, but as also shown in the screenshot, and after debugging my code, the **new_survey_draft** object was created with **id=pk=270** , while the DB table shown in the other window to the right doesn't have the new row with the **id=270**.

Even when setting a break point in the **publish_survey_draft()** called after the object instantiation, I called the **SurveyDraft.objects.get(pk=270)** which returned the object, but still there is not **id=270** in the DB table.

And finally, after resuming the code and returning from all definitions, the row was successfully added to the DB table with the **id=270**.

I'm wondering what's happening behind the seen, and is it possible that Django stores data in objects without persisting to DB on real-time, and only persists the data all together on some later execution point?

I've been stuck in this for hours and couldn't find anything helpful online, so I really appreciate any advice regarding the issue.

[image]

Comment: That's just transactions, surely.

Comment: @DanielRoseman What do you mean? Can you clarify please?

Comment: I found what I suppose you meant by "transactions" on my own, and below is my answer. It would be much more helpful and appreciated if you explained a little bit more about the concept instead of your comment above, and giving a down vote for my question. @DanielRoseman But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging deep into this issue, I just found that there is a concept called **Atomic Requests** that's enabled in my Django project by setting the  ***ATOMIC_REQUESTS to True*** in the settings.py under the DATABASES dictionary as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/transactions/#tying-transactions-to-http-requests)

> It works like this. Before calling a view function, Django starts a
>   transaction. If the response is produced without problems, Django
>   commits the transaction. If the view produces an exception, Django
>   rolls back the transaction.

That's why the changes were not persisting in the database while debugging my code using break points, since the changes will only be committed to the DB once the successful response is returned.