# Why is Django database save not permanently saving the update?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using a postgresql database. I am updating a certain field of an existing database row and saving it again. However, this is change not reflecting inside the database (viewing it on DBeaver). The bizarre thing is that the change is properly reflected using the debugger and querying the database with the same ID.

```
 p_details: ProjectDetails = ProjectDetails.objects.get(pk=res['id'])

 p_details.build_status = ProjectBuildEnums.PASSED.value if res['error'] is None else ProjectBuildEnums.FAILED.value
p_details.build_error = json.dumps(res)
p_details.save(update_fields=["build_status", "build_error"])
sleep(1)
new_p = ProjectDetails.objects.get(pk=res['id'])
```

This is the line of code where I am updating the database. After the save, I am requerying the database using the same primary key ID. At this instance, using the debugger, I can see the changes clearly. However, viewing this database using DBeaver after refreshing the database doesnt show this change yet. Once the view is complete, and I refresh the database again, this change  is still not present, meaning the update has disappeared. Does anyone know what is going on? After the above lines, the ProjectDetails database is no longer being touched. No errors are shown in the terminal/debugger either.

[image: The debugger showing the changes properly (build_error and build_status)]

[image: Database reverting the changes]

Comment: This might be silly but, you are looking at the correct database right? Can you confirm with the `DATABASES` setting? Or are you running this code in an atomic block or do you have `ATOMIC_REQUESTS` set to `True` (If so there's probably an exception causing your changes to be rolled back)?

Comment: nothing seems wrong with your Django query, because you query again and got the new data, my presumption is that you are viewing the wrong database, or you didn't refresh the DB correctly with DBeaver

Comment: Nope, I am 100% sure that I am viewing the correct database. The database update is being reverted for whatever reason. Once the view completes, the database is going back to the original data. I can confirm this through the frontend (which fetches the latest details and shows the non-updated original data)

Comment: Related: [Model object not creating from inside except block or right before raising exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72789083/model-object-not-creating-from-inside-except-block-or-right-before-raising-excep) and [Django model isn't persisting data to DB on real-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40908465/django-model-isnt-persisting-data-to-db-on-real-time) I am assuming the transactions are probably the issue here, you either have an atomic block or `ATOMIC_REQUESTS = True`